# Rails 4 composite_primary_keys gem and custom action issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, composite-primary-key

I have a join model called subscriptions which ties users to groups they are subscribed to. The group owner has to confirm a subscription to the group before the user can access the groups content. I am trying to create the 'confirm subscription' button for pending subscriptions however I am running into a little bit of trouble with finding a subscription with the composite primary keys gem. I have the gem all setup and working. I have created a custom action called pending_subscriptions in the subscriptions controller and a corresponding view. The code in the action is:

```
def pending_subscriptions
    @group = Group.where(:owner_id => current_user.id)
    @pending_subscriptions = Subscription.where(group_id: @group, role: "pending")
    @subscription = Subscription.find([params[:user_id], params[:group_id]])
   end
```

I get an error:

```
Couldn't find Subscription with ID=, WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" IS NULL AND "subscriptions"."group_id" IS NULL
```

How do I correctly instantiate the @subscription instance so I use it in a form_for to pass params to the update action via a put request?

Answer (score 0):

As you can clearly see in logs `params[:user_id]` is empty (nil), as same as a `params[:group_id]`.

So you're not passing some parameters properly - please take a look into logs, which parameters are actually received by server. I would guess:

```
@subscription = Subscription.find([params[:subscription][:user_id], params[:subscription][:group_id]])
```

or, if you're using proper strong_parameters:

```
@subscription = Subscription.find([subscription_params[:user_id], subscription_params[:group_id]])
```

Comment: I can't see anything in the log:

`Started GET "/subscriptions/pending_subscriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-28 23:30:31 +0000
Processing by SubscriptionsController#pending_subscriptions as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'a1a178522594ce4a77f2a5b81fea53eeb7dba6d4' LIMIT 1
  Subscription Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" IS NULL AND "subscriptions"."group_id" IS NULL
Completed 404 Not Found in 53ms`

Comment: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Subscription with ID=, WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" IS NULL AND "subscriptions"."group_id" IS NULL):
  app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:36:in `pending_subscriptions'`

Comment: So you're not sending any parameters to the server after all! What will happen if you append ?user_id=1&group_id=1 to the url?

Comment: To be honest I think I'm going about this wrong. My problem is actually that I have a do block doing the following `<% @pending_subscriptions.each do |pending_subscription| %>`

I want to take one of the pending_subscription objects and pass it to the update action in the controller using a form_for.

Comment: I've (sort of) solved my issue. The correct thing to do is not to use composite primary keys.